# How to fast custom AI model prediction through API?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, mlops

I develop API using Django for AI model but it's prediction is slow and i have lots of request which take time to execute through AI API, I need help to handle multiple Request at same time

Answer (score 2):

If your AI model is stateless meaning new request can be processed independent of the previous requests, then you can run multiple instances of your AI model. You can use a Deployment with multiple replicas. Then, use a Service to load-balance between the instances.

Comment: can i use kubernetes  for this?

Comment: Yes. Btw, where are running your application now?

Comment: i am running it on aws instance, but if made replica for it then it is expensive for us,